Browser tab-switching hotkey causes window aligning
I recently upgraded to OS 15 and suddenly there comes a hotkey conflict. I used to switch between browser tabs with fn+ctrl+up/down in Firefox, but now it always causes app window resizing/aligning, i.e., this function. But I couldn't find where to reset the hotkeys for this window control.
